# Distance between fundamental domain and its translates

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, group-actions, covering-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\tilde{M}$ its universal cover. Suppose that $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely generated. Let $\tilde{g}$ be the lift of $g$ to $\tilde{M}$, and let $d$ denote the induced distance function on $\tilde{M}$.

Let $L\colon\pi_1(M)\to\mathbb{N}$ be a fixed length function, and let $F\subseteq\tilde{M}$ be a fundamental domain for the action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde M$.

(By fundamental domain, I mean that $F$ is the closure of an open subset of $\tilde{M}$ such that for any $g\in\pi_1(M)$, the interiors of $g\cdot F$ and $F$ have no common points, and $\{g\cdot F\}_{g\in\pi_1(M)}$ form a cover of $\tilde M$.)

**Question:** Given any sequence $(g_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\pi_1(M)$ such that $\lim_{i\to\infty}l(g_i)=\infty$, is it true that
$$\lim_{i\to\infty}d(F,g_i\cdot F)=\infty,$$
where $g_i\cdot F$ is the translate of $F$ by the action of $g_i$?

*Remark:* If $M$ is compact, then the answer should be yes, since the action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde{M}$ is always proper. In the non-compact case, I would expect the answer to be no, but would like an example that shows this.

Comment: You should at least explain your definition of a length function (especially since $\pi_1(M)$ might be infinitely generated) and of a fundamental domain (it will really make a difference).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah yes, let's assume $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Ok, what about your notion of a fundamental domain?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I've added that also.

Comment: Then your question has tautologically positive answer (due to the local finiteness condition), assuming that $(M,g)$ is complete.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, how about if I remove it?

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to local finiteness (provided $(M,g)$ is complete).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Your condition implies local finiteness but is much stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer, I will assume that
$$
d(A,B)=\inf_{a\in A, b\in B} d(a,b). 
$$

Here is a simple and classical example. Consider the modular group $\Gamma=PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ and its standard fundamental domain $F$. Let $u_n\in \Gamma$ be any sequence corresponding to (strictly) upper-triangular matrices. Then  for each $u_n$, $d(u_nF,F)=0$.

Or, for a simpler example consider the subgroup $\Gamma< PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$ generated by the translation $u: z\mapsto z+1$ (in the upper half-plane model). As $F$ take
$$
\{z: Im(z)>0, 0\le Re(z)\le 1\}. 
$$
Then for each $\gamma\in \Gamma$,
$$
d(F, \gamma F)=0. 
$$

Comment: I'm a little confused about the notation. I guess as $F$ could be $\{z\colon Im(z)>0,0\leq Re(z)\leq 1\}$?

Comment: @geometricK: Right.

Comment: I suppose here $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is actually the fundamental group of an orbifold instead of a manifold right? I wonder if it's possible to construct a manifold example out of this.

Comment: @geometricK: Right. As for a manifold example, any torsion-free finite index subgroup would work. Or work with the unit tangent bundle of this orbifold, it will be a manifold.